# JavaScript inheritance: why copy from an instance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

In JavaScript, when I want to inherit the properties from a "class", I write:

`Car.prototype = new Vehicle();`

Why do I assign an instance of vehicle here?

Why don't we write `Car.prototype = Vehicle;` or `Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;` instead? Why copy from an instance?

Comment: *Why copy from an instance?* - note that `Car.prototype = new Vehicle()` does **not** make a copy of the instance. It assigns to `Car.prototype` a *reference* to the instance. No copy is made.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should really do

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```

The reasons are involved, but suffice to say that that's a better way to get a new object for your `Car` prototype and ensure that it inherits from the `Vehicle` prototype.

Now, the **reason** you want a new object for the `Car` prototype is that if you're bothering to make a *subclass* you'll probably want specialized behaviors that *do* apply to the subclass but *don't* apply to the more general parent class. You need a new object for those new properties; otherwise, you'd be adding those behavior properties to the `Vehicle` prototype, and all Vehicles would have access.

Finally, setting `Car.prototype` to just `Vehicle` doesn't make much sense. That would *work*, in that it would not cause an exception, but it would set the `Car` prototype to be the `Vehicle` constructor function itself.

Comment: T. J. Crowder has a great answer floating around somewhere that goes into detail about creating prototype objects for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically .prototype is an object. And by making direct assignment

```
Car.prototype = Vehicle.prototype
```

you are copying object over a reference.

And if you try to modify Car.prototype in order to add new features, like making bip sounds, you will modify Vehicle.prototype too since they are both referencing the same object.

And that is not what you probably want.